# Widget layout within container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89IjJ.png)

Hey, so I am trying to format these text widgets inside this green bubble. For some reason there is a huge space in between '45' and 'lbs'. I am not sure why this is. I would like the space to be consistent between all the text children in the column. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
return Container(
      decoration: bubbleBoxDecoration,
      height: bubbleDiameter.toDouble(),
      width: bubbleDiameter.toDouble(),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Upper Body',
              style: labelTextStyle,
            ),

            Text(
              '45',
              style: weightTextStyle,
            ),
            Text(
              'lbs',
              style: unitTextStyle,
            ),
```

Comment: you can try to use this ```mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly```

Comment: try structStyle of Text, https://medium.com/@najeira/control-text-height-using-strutstyle-4b9b5151668b

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
```

on your Column, for achieving consistent spaces between them

Answer (score 0):

I needed to adjust the height of the text. There was some "invisible" height on the 45 that needed adjustment.